# how does the Double.parseDouble("100d") gets no error

Tags: java

`Double.parseDouble("100a");`  // getting the error as expected
But why does the below line doesn't gets the error

`Double.parseDouble("100d");`

Please explain me.

Comment: `100d` should denote the integer 100 which should be treated as a double.

Comment: `100d` or `100f` here `d` and `f ` have special meaning.(i.e `d ` means `double` type and `f ` means `float`

Answer (score 6):

According to the source code, the [`Double.parseDouble(String s)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Double.java#Double.parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) method uses the [`FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(String s)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString%28java.lang.String%29) to parse the provided argument.

There, you can see that there's a check if the provided `String` ends with `'D'`, `'d'`, `'F'` or `'f'` and if it doesn't, then a `NumberFormatException` is thrown:

```
if (i < l &&
   ((i != l - 1) ||
    (in.charAt(i) != 'f' &&
     in.charAt(i) != 'F' &&
     in.charAt(i) != 'd' &&
     in.charAt(i) != 'D'))) {
       break parseNumber; // go throw exception
     }
```

Comment: I agree with OP that this is a weird specification ...  Is there another method that does it differently (accepting only what normal people would consider a floating point)?

Comment: @Thilo programmers are not normal people, also, is quite known than java parse the `d`, `D` etc... as double numbers and is really easy for all when we do `double d = 10d`. IMO it must match in both cases to follow java specs where a `10d` is a double...

Comment: Honestly, can't tell. I'll have to check.

Comment: @JordiCastilla: Don't agree at all. Parsing numbers from external data does not have to follow Java language specs for literals at all. This is still okay, leading "0" that leads to the number being parsed as octal is even worse.

Comment: @JordiCastilla Also note, that Long#parseLong *does not* allow the type specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

`d` represents `double`.

```
public static double parseDouble(String s) throws NumberFormatException

Throws:
NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable double.
```

`100d` is a parsable `double` string that's why it doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) says:

> Returns a new double initialized to the value represented by the specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Double.

So we look at [the javadoc for `Double::valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) which gives the detailed acceptable syntax, in particular:

> Sign<sub>opt</sub> FloatingPointLiteral

where `FloatingPointLiteral` is as defined in the JLS. So we go to [JLS #3.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) and you see that it can end with `f`, `F`, `d` or `D`, as expected.

---

If you want to only accept "human-readable doubles", you can use [a `DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).